# How to link pnglite library in c?

Tags: c, linker, libraries, ubuntu

I installed from kubuntu's package management this handy pnglite library. It contains just one header file "pnglite.h" and one object file "pnglite.o". I have found out where those files are, but I don't know how to link them. I'm using netbeans, but don't know how to link them in there. Also I don't understand how to link them at console.

I have a little test program that I would like to test, but I get the error message "undefined reference to function: XXXXXXX". Both netbeans and at console I'm using gcc. That header file is in /usr/include directory, object file is in /usr/lib directory and my test program is under my programming directory at my home directory.

Should I put that header and object into the same directory as where my source is? Or is there a way to link them from their current locations? I know that it should be possible to link them from where they are at the moment and I would like to know and understand how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Its really, really odd for them to package a library like that. Even if its just a single object, it really should be a proper shared object, else this exact kind of confusion ensues. Not to mention updates to the library that don't effect programs that are already linked. Are you sure there's no .so in /usr/lib for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `/usr/lib/pnglite.o` to your linking invocation of gcc, plus any shared libraries that `pnglite` requires (from your comment it appears to require zlib).  Eg if your source is in `myapp1.c` and `myapp2.c`, then:

```
gcc -c myapp1.c
gcc -c myapp2.c
gcc -o myapp myapp1.o myapp2.o /usr/lib/pnglite.o -lz
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess that would do it in common case. I tried that, but now I get many error messages referring to that pnglite.o saying "undefined reference to 'crc32' ". No idea what that's about.

Comment: Your linker fails because either your app or pnglite.o uses a resource crc32 that is not in the compiled object files or a shared library.. have you used the same shared libraries as when you builded without pnglib?

Comment: @zaplec: The pnglite object appears to need to be linked against some shared libraries - for example `crc32` is in zlib, so you add `-lz` to the link line too (I have updated the answer).

Comment: Thanks caf. Now it's working and it's my mistake that I didn't read carefully enough that documentation of pnglite as it is said there that pnglite uses zlib.